# Poll.objects.filter() returning multiple instances of the same poll

Tags: python, django, django-apps

Following the tutorial at djangoproject, I have created a Poll with 2 polls.

```
In [14]: Poll.objects.all()
Out[14]: [<Poll: poll1>, <Poll: poll2>]
```

When I apply the filter

```
In [18]: Poll.objects.filter(choice__choice_text__isnull=False)
```

The following is returned, even though there are only 2 polls.

```
Out[18]: [<Poll: poll1>, <Poll: poll1>, <Poll: poll1>, <Poll: poll2>, <Poll: poll2>, <Poll: poll2>]
```

Why are there multiple occurences of the same poll? The goal of the filter is to filter out the polls that don't have any choices. In addition, other filters like below do work.

```
In [19]: Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now)
Out[19]: [<Poll: poll1>, <Poll: poll2>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the polls being returned have choices? It looks like it's returning one instance of a poll for every associated choice, resulting in duplicates. To get rid of these, use `distinct()`:

```
Poll.objects.filter(choice__choice_text__isnull=False).distinct()
```

**Update**: let's go under the hood. Your first query is spanning the Poll-Choice relationship, using a JOIN behind-the-scenes to "combine" the two tables. (JOINs can be complicated, so if this is confusing I suggest researching them.) Your query is returning a Poll object for every Choice whose text is null.

On the other hand, your second query is simply selecting from your Poll table. The line:

```
Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now)
```

translates to `SELECT * FROM poll WHERE pub_date <= tz.now`. For more details on field lookups, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups). For more guidance on spanning relationships, see [the docs again](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Yes each post has 3. Why does the 2nd filter return distinct polls while the first does not?

Comment: @student He updated his post with a very good explanation, just pinging you so that you see it.

Comment: Thanks Cianan, do you think the way i did the filter was the most effective way of getting the polls with no choices?

Comment: I do, since only the choices "know" which polls have them.